# Component Pascal setup environment

Tags: jvm

I am trying to set up an environment for Component Pascal.
I chose the JVM option. I set a new system variable JROOT and added to the Path variable.

I try to run a new file I created via command line and got this error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class CP.gpcp.gpcp`

Answer (score 0):

You must set a CPROOT environment variable to the instalation path of GPCP, something like

```
CPROOT=$HOME/gpcp;export CPROOT;
```

then add the bin directory to the GPCP executables to the PATH,

```
PATH=$CPROOT/bin:$PATH;export PATH;
```

both, in your .bashrc

Compile your CP program with

```
cprun gpcp <program>.cp
```

and execute with

```
cprun <program>
```